# Error al consumir un servicio rest en angular v6

Tags: datatables, rest, angular6

Hasta Ahora tengo lo siguiente, 
tengo mi provider con el siguiente codigo

```
 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class GetActuariosService {
 configUrl = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 }
 getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
}
}
```

y en mi componente lo recibo asi:

```
ngOnInit( ) {
 this.service.getConfig().subscribe((data) => {
        this.items = data;
 });
```

y en el lado del html lo quiero pintar en una tabla:

```
<table datatable class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nº</th>
            <th>Nº</th>
            <th>Nº</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr *ngFor="let info of items">
            <th scope="row">{{info.nombre}}</th>
            <th scope="row">{{info.nombre}}</th>
            <th scope="row">{{info.nombre}}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

y me pinta los datos correctamente pero me agrega un nota abajo que dice 'No hay datos disponibles en la tabla',

[image: impresion de datos]

y si busco algun dato existente en el campo buscar, me aparece lo mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es como si esos datos no existieran dentro de la tabla, mas sin embargo pinta los datos utilizo esta libreria para las tablas https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) En la pagina oficial de [angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way) podes customizar el texto verificando la cantidad de valores en tu lista de items

```
HTML

  <tbody *ngIf="items?.length != 0">
      <tr *ngFor="let person of items">
          <td>{{ info.nombre }}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody *ngIf="items?.length == 0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No hay datos!</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>


CSS
/*
   server-side-angular-way.component.css
*/
.no-data-available {
  text-align: center;
}

/*
   src/styles.css (i.e. your global style)
*/
.dataTables_empty {
  display: none;
}
```

2) Tambien hay un issue en ese repositorio de git con tu problema [issue-1260](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1260) en github.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      dtInstance.on( 'draw.dt', function () {
      if($('.dataTables_empty').length > 0)
      {
        $('.dataTables_empty').remove();
      }
    });

    });
  }
```